# java's object visibility under multiple locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility, locks

Here's the problem I'm facing. On running the below code, I'm sometimes getting stale data when printing the content of B.  I can't really understand why this is happening since updating and receiving the contents of B are protected by B's lock.

Notice that the during update to B, both the locks of A and B are held. 
While accessing the contents of B, only a single lock is held.

Also Notice that B.updated() is not synchronized, but I don't think this is the problem since I'm making sure that the updated counter is set to 2, before I access the content of B.

```
class B {
  Object data
  int updated = 0

  // get and set protected by B's monitor
  synchronized Object getData() {
    return data;
  }
  synchronized setData(Object d) {
    data = d;
    updated += 1;
  }
  // deliberately not synchronized
  int updated() { return updated; }
}

class A {
    B b
    A() {
        new Thread t = new Thread(new UpdaterThread());
        t.start();
    }

   // when B is updated both A and B monitors are held
    synchronized String setB(Object data) {
      b.setData(data);
   }

   class UpdateThread implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
       // updating B to new Value
       setB("B2");
     }
   }
}

public static void main(String[] _) {
   B b = new B();  
   b.setData("B1");
   A a = new A();
   while (b.updated() == 1) {
     // wait for updated to reach 2
   } 
   println(b.getData());  // prints "B1" sometimes, but very rarely.
}
```

Comment: I should add that, this is a higly simplied code from a library I'm currently using.

Comment: Don't forget to put the semicolons after declarations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are expecting the code to be [sequentially consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_consistency). However, Java guarantees *sequential consistency* only, if there are no *data races* in the code.

> Also Notice that B.updated() is not synchronized, but I don't think this is the problem since I'm making sure that the updated counter is set to 2, before I access the content of B.

That's the problem. You have a *data race* on the variable updated, because one thread writes to it, and another threads reads from it without any synchronization.

If you make the variable `volatile`, the code will work, because there are no *data races* on `volatile` variables.

Comment: I don't think making the variable volatile is sufficient.  The volatile keyword will flush the value to main memory for visibility in other threads; however, I don't think it guarantees synchronization with updates to other variables.  The value of 'updated' can still get flushed first, with the result that the main() method can still see `b` updated when the value of `data` has not yet been flushed and is not yet visible.

Comment: @WarrenDew: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688697/is-a-write-to-a-volatile-a-memory-barrier-in-java