# Does function returning a volatile variable need synchronization?

Tags: java, volatile

`setGameState()` and `getGameState()` can be called from different threads. `m_gameState` is volatile so its value/change could be visible to other threads.

**Question:** 
Do the functions need to be `synchronized` or does volatile on the variable suffice?

```
private volatile EGameState m_gameState;

public void setGameState(EGameState a_gameState) {
   m_gameState = a_gameState;
}

public EGameState getGameState() {
   return m_gameState;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a write to a volatile a memory-barrier in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688697/is-a-write-to-a-volatile-a-memory-barrier-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Access to the volatile variable acts as though it is synchronized on itself.

Accessing a volatile variable never holds a lock, it is not suitable for cases where we want to read-update-write as an atomic operation.Here you are required to use a synchronized block.

For other cases it will suffice if you didn't use synchronization(like normal get and set)

Comment: Using the phrase "synchronized on itself" does not correctly describe what a volatile does.  Synchronization implies mutual coordination when accessed by multiple threads.  There is absolutely no guarantee of accurate modification when a volatile is modified by two threads concurrently; only that the last modification becomes the dominating one.  This is why compareAndSet is used heavily in the lock mechanics in conjunction with volatile.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. Do you require the updates of your `EGameState` field to be *ordered* or not?
If they must be ordered, than a `synchronized` block (on `this`) is mandatory, if not, `volatile` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If `volatile` keyword is used with variable, all threads will get latest value of the variable from main memory. Note that it does not acquire a lock so if you want to do any atomic operation, `volatile` is not sufficient. For atomic operations `synchronized` is used.In your case you are only reading the value `m_gameState = a_gameState;` so volatile is sufficient.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where do you get `volatile` is used for visibility?  `volatile` is an automated Load and Store Fence.  Reading from a `volatile` automatically performs a Load Fence and writing automatically performs a Store Fence.  This is the reason why it is used often in the lock API.  `volatile` is the underlying type of all the Atomic* classes.

Comment: `volatile` keyword guarantees visibility(updated value will be visible to all the threads) of changes to variables across threads. 
Check: 
  [1]: https://medium.com/@siddhusingh/volatile-visibility-in-jvm-3d2044da017c
  [2]: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

Comment: Because `visibility` is ambiguous in your answer and could be mistaken for access-modifiers.  JSR-133 is very careful how `visible` is used in the explanation of the memory behaviors of `volatile`.  For clarity, you can change your answer to 'memory visibility' or simply remove the first sentence.

Comment: Got your point. Updated the answer. Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

- http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html
- https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java
- [Is a write to a volatile a memory-barrier in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688697/is-a-write-to-a-volatile-a-memory-barrier-in-java)

`volatile` is an automatic Load/Store Fence in memory; read and writes are atomic; you don't need to synchronize anything in your posted example.