# Guava: MemoizingSupplier thread safety

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

Guava Suppliers-class contains MemoizingSupplier:

```java
static class MemoizingSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T>, Serializable {
    final Supplier<T> delegate;
    transient volatile boolean initialized;
    // "value" does not need to be volatile; visibility piggy-backs
    // on volatile read of "initialized".
    transient T value;

    MemoizingSupplier(Supplier<T> delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override public T get() {
      // A 2-field variant of Double Checked Locking.
      if (!initialized) {
        synchronized (this) {
          if (!initialized) {
            T t = delegate.get();
            value = t;
            initialized = true;
            return t;
          }
        }
      }
      return value;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
      return "Suppliers.memoize(" + delegate + ")";
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
  }
```

Could someone explain what does that comment mean?

> "value" does not need to be volatile; visibility piggy-backs on volatile read of "initialized".

How can volatile on "initialized" field affect "value" field? 
According to [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) article we can get inconsistent combination of "initialized" and "value" fields (eg. true+null). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence basically means that the reads & writes of `value` are ordered in a certain way with the volatile reads & writes that guarantees that the written value will be visible to the read.

---

#### (Simplified) proof

If the value is not initialized, the program will execute those two statements:

```
value = t;          //normal write
initialized = true; //volatile write
```

and if the value is initialized, the program will execute those two statements:

```
if(!initialized) { ... } //volatile read
return value;            //normal read
```

Thanks to volatile semantics, you have a happens-before relationship between the volatile write and the volatile read and the normal read in `return value` is guaranteed to see the write at `value = t`. This works because the normal write is ***before*** the volatile write and the normal read is ***after*** the volatile read.

---

#### Why the order is important

For example if the program was written like this:

```
initialized = true;
value = t;
```

`return value` could return a null value because the write here does not happen before the volatile write which acts as a memory barrier and therefore it does not benefit from the volatile semantics any more.

Comment: another [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108541/happens-before-relationships-with-volatile-fields-and-synchronized-blocks-in-jav) and good [article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile)