# Does Java allow a volatile read to be optimized away if the value isn't needed, also removing the happens-before synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, java-memory-model, happens-before

The following code sample shows a common way to demonstrate concurrency issues caused by a missing happens-before relationship.

```java
private static /*volatile*/ boolean running = true;
    
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    running = false;
}
```

If `running` is `volatile`, the program is guaranteed to terminate after approximately one second. However, if `running` isn't `volatile`, the program isn't guaranteed to terminate at all (since there is no happens-before relationship or guarantee for visibility of changes to the variable `running` in this case) and that's exactly what happens in my tests.

According to [JLS 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) one can also enforce a happens-before relationship by writing to and reading another `volatile` variable `running2`, as shown in the following code sample.

```java
private static boolean running = true;
private static volatile boolean running2 = true;
    
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running2 || running) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    running = false;
    running2 = false;
}
```

The `volatile` variable `running2` is read in each loop iteration and when it is read as `false` after approximately one second, it is also guaranteed that the variable `running` is read as `false` subsequently, due to the happens-before relationship. Thus the program is guaranteed to terminate after approximately one second and that's exactly what happens in my tests.

However, when I put the read of the variable `running2` into an empty `if` statement inside the `while` loop, as shown in the following code sample, the program doesn't terminate in my tests.

```java
private static boolean running = true;
private static volatile boolean running2 = true;
    
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                if (running2) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    running = false;
    running2 = false;
}
```

The idea here is that a `volatile` read of `running2` is like a compiler memory barrier: the compiler has to make asm that re-reads non-`volatile` variables because the read of `running2` might have synchronized-with a release operation in another thread. That would guarantee visibility of new values in non-volatile variables like `running`.

But my JVM seems not to be doing that.  **Is this a compiler or JVM bug, or does the JLS allow such optimizations where a `volatile` read is removed when the value isn't needed?** (It's only controlling an empty `if` body, so the program behaviour doesn't depend on the value being read, only on creating a happens-before relationship.)

I thought the JLS applies to the source code and since `running2` is `volatile`, the effect of reading the variable shouldn't be allowed to be removed due to an optimization. Is this a compiler or JVM bug, or is there a specification, which actually allows such optimizations?

Comment: Did you try reversing the order of running2 and running in your loop condition? Also, can you explain *why* 17.4.5 says that auxillary variables, `running` in this case, are also updated when *any* volatile variable is read? I think a synchronized block would cause that.

Comment: @matt reversing the order of the variables entirely misses the purpose of the question, but the answer is that no happens-before relationship occurs because the `volatile` field isn't read. And yes, reading any `volatile` field ensures a happens-before relationship for all changes that happened before due to the example in the linked paragraph: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

Comment: I think you're drawing the wrong conclussion. If you have `while( running2 || running )` then "running" never gets read because "||" is a short circuit operator. Therefore it never gets optimized out. You set running2 to false, and running2 is volatile so it has to be updated (happens-before) *then* `running` gets read for the first time and the loop ends.

Comment: @matt sorry I linked the wrong example, alternatively see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108892/3882565 an many other answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: @matt "I think you're drawing the wrong conclussion. ..." No, what you are saying is exactly what I want to show with this example, plus the fact that `running` is read correctly as `false` (due to the happens-before relationship) as soon as it's actually read.

Comment: The answer you link there is directly contradicted in the JLS you link. "Thread 1 writes to s happens before Thread 1 writes to b (program order rule)" The JLS says that if nothing is affected it is ok to re-order that write.

Comment: @stonar96 what platform are you on? I can't reproduce third case on MacOS x86/Java 17, moreover, `running2 = false` is not required.

Comment: @matt "To show what you want to show, ..." But that's not what I want to show. What you are saying is correct. "Then when you set `running` to false, it will not stop the loop. ..." Yes, but for two reasons actually: 1) because `running2` is still `true` and 2) because the thread isn't guaranteed to see `running` as `false`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I'm using the Eclipse JDT core compiler with compiler compliance level 1.8 and execution environment JavaSE-1.8 (jdk-17.0.1.12-hotspot) on Windows 10 64 bit to test this. The write `running2 = false;` is required afaik to ensure a happens-before relationship.

Comment: So you're hoping that reading a `volatile` will act as a compile-time memory barrier (like GNU C `asm("" ::: "memory")`) and force the JVM to make asm that re-reads the non-volatile as well.  (Because that happens after a load that might have synced-with.)  Yeah, this sounds reasonable, if the compiler can't optimize away the volatile read even though its value isn't needed (only controlling an empty if).  So basically the question is whether the JLS allows removing such loads, removing the only thing that could be syncing with another thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes exactly, and that's what I would expect to happen according to the JLS.

Comment: @stonar96 just checked, the same code compiled by OpenJDK and Eclipse JDT behaves differently, OpenJDK behaviour meets your expectations.

Comment: @stonar96 `The write running2 = false; is required afaik to ensure a happens-before relationship` - where is the local value of `running` visible to `main` thread stored after exiting `#main` method (i.e. after `main` thread exited)? we have written it, we can't lose it.

Comment: In your example with the `if(running2) {}`, you claim Thread doesn't finish execution because the if statement is optimized out. Therefore there is never a volatile read, so the while loop coninues execution. You're claiming this is a bug because the volatile read should act like a memory barrier and both `running` and `running2` should be updated. I don't think this is a bug because I don't think `running` needs to be updated when there is an update to `running2`. It would help your question if you can show that with the JLS. Also, the if example exits fine for me, `openjdk version "11.0.15"`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109277/2067492) claims that JCIP says that all the changes should be visible. It would be good if there was a reference to the JLS though.

Comment: @PeterCordes the compiler is allowed to remove a volatile load/store (or synchronized block) if the sole purpose is to act like a memory fence. For examples see https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_15_VolatilesAreNotFences.java. Therefor I'm pretty sure that in the last example, the empty `if (running2) {}` could be optimized out.

Comment: @pveentjer: Interesting, that sounds like an answer, especially if you know where to look in the JLS to justify that.  (Hopefully it's not like user19607013's answer suggests, and based on allowing an infinite delay in visibility of a volatile write.)

Answer (score 4):

> ... **does the JLS allow it to remove a volatile read when the value isn't needed?** (It's only controlling an empty if body, so the program behaviour doesn't depend on the value read, only on creating a happens-before.)

According to [17.4. Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) of the JLS:

> The memory model describes possible behaviors of a program. An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.

So the JLS permits literally anything in runtime as long as result of the execution is "legal".

By "result of the execution" the JLS means all the external actions that the program performs: operations with files and network sockets, various system calls (e.g. reading current time), etc.
I believe that [17.4.9. Observable Behavior and Nonterminating Executions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.9) of the JLS is about that (or something like that).

In your example the only external action is sleeping for 1s, so your program can be "optimized" to:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

If [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73090830) is correct in that an infinite loop is also a legal execution, then, I guess, your program can be "optimized" to:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(true);
    }
```

---

One more time: the runtime is allowed to do anything as long as it performs the same external actions as one of the legal executions allowed by the JLS.

To clarify things more, let's get legal executions for our example.

**General Algorithm**

The general algorithm is described in [17.4. Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) of the JLS.

> The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread, with the exception that the values seen by each read are determined by the memory model.

So we assume that actions in each thread are executed sequentially, one-by-one.
The only difference from a single-threaded program is that for a variable accessed from multiple threads a read might return an "unexpected" value.

The rule to to get all possible values for a read is this:

> Informally, a read `r` is allowed to see the result of a write `w` if there is no happens-before ordering to prevent that read.

In other words, a read of some variable returns:

- either the last write to than variable in `happens-before` order
- or any write to than variable, that is not related to the read by `happens-before`

Note that the algorithm doesn't allow to "optimize out" anything.

**Legal Executions For The Example**

Now let's apply the algorithm to our example to find legal executions.
(Note: for simplicity we'll omit cases like unexpected `Error` and termination of the program by the OS)

The main thread has no reads of shared variables, so it behaves just like a single-threaded program.
It's actions:

```java
new Thread(){...}.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
running = false;
running2 = false;
```

The second thread is a loop with 2 reads.
So we get a sequence of actions:

```java
read(running == true)
read(running2 == ?)
read(running == true)
read(running2 == ?)
...
read(running == false)
```

The sequence ends as soon as a read of `running` returns `false`.

What values can the reads return according to the JLS?
Let's first note that `running2` is volatile, which means that reads ands writes to it happen in a global order (it's called [synchronization order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)) and are visible to all threads in that order.
So:

- before the write `running2 = false` becomes visible to the second thread:

  - `running2 == true`
    This is the initial write (the only visible write).
  - `running == true` or `running == false`
    For every read of `running`:

    - the initial write (`running = true`) `happens-before` the read
    - the write `running = false` is not related by `happens-before` with the read

    So each read `running == ?` can return any of the two writes randomly.

    ```java
    Main Thread              Thread2                 

    [...]                    [...]                   
      ↓ (happens-before)       ↓ (happens-before)    
    running = false;         running2 == true;       
      ↓ (happens-before)       ↓ (happens-before)    
    running2 = false;        running == true | false
    ```
- after the write `running2 = false` becomes visible to the second thread:

  - `running2 == false`
    This is the latest visible write.
  - `running == false`
    Because `running2 == false`
    => `running2 = false` `happens-before` `running2 == false`
    => transitively  `running = false` `happens-before` `running == false`

    ```java
    Main Thread              Thread2              

    [...]                                         
      ↓ (happens-before)                          
    running = false;                              
      ↓ (happens-before)     [...]                
    running2 = false;          ↓ (happens-before) 
      └--------------------> running2 == false;   
          (happens-before)     ↓ (happens-before) 
                             running == false;
    ```

    As a result, the second thread finishes when the write `running2 = false` becomes visible to it.

To sum up, all legal executions of the second thread:

1. can start with this sequence:

```java
read(running == true)
read(running2 == true)
[... repeat the fragment above ...]
```

2. end with:

- either:

  ```java
  ...
  read(running2 == false)
  read(running == false)
  ```

  This is the case when the thread sees `running2 = false` and then is guaranteed to see `running = false`.
- or with:

  ```java
  ...
  read(running == false)
  ```

  This is the case when the thread doesn't see `running2 = false`, but the sees `running = false`.
- or never ends.
  This is the case when the thread sees neither `running2 = false` nor `running = false`.

If you can "optimize out" a volatile read and the result of the execution will be the same as the results of some legal executions described above, then this optimization is legal.

---

Regarding the [AdvancedJMM_15_VolatilesAreNotFences](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_15_VolatilesAreNotFences.java) test mentioned in the comments.

It doesn't seem to me that this test demonstrates that the compiler is allowed to remove a volatile load/store if the value isn't used.

IMO it shows that `volatile` is weaker than `UNSAFE.storeFence() + UNSAFE.loadFence()`.
Basically it's a demonstration of the [Roach Motel](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_jmm_interpretation_roach_motel) optimization:
[image: write can be reordered before release]
[image: read can be reordered after acquire]
[image: read/write can be moved inside acquire+release blocks]

[AdvancedJMM_14_SynchronizedAreNotFences](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_14_SynchronizedAreNotFences.java) is different because it uses `synchronized (new Object()) {}` — there are no shared variables and no `happens-before` relations.

---

P.S. @pveentjer [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/129105510) in the comments this:

> The non-normative section of the JVM does talk about visibility; so a change should become visible to other threads at some point.

Does anyone have a link and a quote to support that?
I cannot find it anywhere, but, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/129105344) by Peter Cordes, it would be really usefull to know that Java (or even only some JVMs) doesn't allow an infinite delay in visibility of a volatile write.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. However, I'm still not fully convinced about the actual point in both answers, namely that the third bullet point "or it never ends" is a valid execution (or at least intended to be a valid execution). The reason for my doubts is that this would essentially mean (provided that my understanding of the answer correct) that it's impossible in Java to reliably send a signal from one thread to another thread (in reasonable real time) in any case. Or does this only happen in the cases in my question because there is no external (observable) action that violates?

Comment: For example would the program be guaranteed to terminate, if I print debug messages at the end of `main` and inside the loop to get external (observable) actions? If the latter question can be answered with a "yes", then I think I can accept the answer.

Comment: @stonar96 Regarding "'it never ends' is a valid execution". Personally I looked in both The Java Language Specification and The Java Virtual Machine Specification, and I cannot find there anything that limits the time that a volatile write propagates to another thread. As a result, at least for now, I have to assume the worst: that it can take forever and 'never ends' is a valid execution. It would be great if someone found a proof of the contrary.

Comment: @stonar96 Regarding "it's impossible in Java to reliably send a signal from one thread to another thread (in reasonable real time)". If a volatile write can take forever to propagate to another thread, than your assumption is true. But to be fair, I suspect that nowadays a program on any programming language can hang forever: for example OS might prioritize other threads for any amount of time.

Comment: @stonar96 In the end, I think that for any program in any language we don't have guarantees (and often specifications) for most levels of execution (the JVM, the OS, hardware, etc.), and we just assume that all of that is implemented in some sane way and expect from all of that some sane behavior.

Comment: @stonar96 "would the program be guaranteed to terminate, if I print debug messages at the end of main and inside the loop to get external (observable) actions?" No. If the volatile write takes forever to propagate, then Thread2 is still not guaranteed to leave the loop, but it will print debug message on every iteration. And every valid Java implementation will have to print the debug messages as well.

Comment: The TLS talks about 'immediately' visible. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3. "and each individual action is atomic and is immediately visible to every thread". Immediately visible makes no sense with SC. "visible as soon as possible" would be better IMHO.

Comment: @pveentjer thank you for providing the quote. IMHO "immediately visible" there means that in a SC  execution a read always sees the latest write. "Latest" here means the total order of actions in SC, the order is synthetic and doesn't even have to reflect the real times when the actions execute. So I don't think the quote means that it cannot take an infinite amount of time for a volatile write to propagate to another thread.

Comment: @qwerty I'm not sure what it means actually :) I have explained in various comments on this page that a read needs to see the most recent write before it in the happens-before order (or a write it is in data-race with). But the happens-before order doesn't need to reflect the happened before order (so the real-time order). So 'immediately' I find a very confusing addition. And for people that do not know the meaning of SC, it can even be misleading since it seems to imply that the JMM is preserving the real time order (which it isn't).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a JVM bug, or does the JLS allow it to remove a volatile read when the value isn't needed?

It's neither.

This execution is valid according to the JLS.

The second thread must finish shortly after it reads `running2 == true`.
But the JLS provides no guarantees about the time it takes for a write in one thread to become visible in another thread.
As a result, your program execution is valid, because it corresponds to the case when the write `running2 = false` takes a very long time to propagate to another thread.

By the way on my java version (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-suse-1.4-x8664, mixed mode)) the program finishes in about 1 second.
This is also a valid execution — this corresponds to the case when the write `running2 = false` propagate to the second thread quicker.

PS you mentioned "memory barrier".
For a memory barrier there typically exists some max time, after which it is guaranteed to propagate to other threads.
But the JLS doesn't operate in terms of memory barriers, doesn't have to use them, and actually guarantees only [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4):

> An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.

PSS If you want to see the real assembly code that the JVM produced for your program you can use [+PrintAssembly](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly).

Comment: Delayed visibility due to sequential consistency not needing to preserve the real-time order of requests is one reason why the loop could keep running. But the removal of a volatile read/write (or synchronized block) that only serves as a fence, is another cause. For a concrete example see

https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_15_VolatilesAreNotFences.java

I believe the 'if(running2){} could be optimized out for that reason.

Comment: `running2` is the `volatile` variable.  (Unfortunately the question picked names that don't help you remember which is which.)  Anyway, `volatile` writes should always be visible to `volatile` reads promptly, shouldn't they?  C++ for example just says "finite time" and "reasonable amount of time" as recommendations; it seems to me disappointing if Java didn't at least strongly recommend that infinite delays shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes The non-normative section of the JVM does talk about visibility; so a change should become visible to other threads at some point. But the JMM itself makes no guarantee how much skewing is allowed (at least I don't recall seeing it).

Comment: @pveentjer: Ok, C++ is the same, that "finite time" is a non-normative note.  ([this answer quotes both notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581645/why-set-the-stop-flag-using-memory-order-seq-cst-if-you-check-it-with-memory/70593598#70593598)).  But is that the only thing that allows optimizing away a volatile load here?  An implementation choice in how to interpret the standard to sometimes allow infinite delays?

Comment: "But the JLS provides no guarantees about the time it takes for a write in one thread to become visible in another thread." Where do you get this from? `running2` is volatile, and any subsequent read should see the updated value. From [17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) "A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread"

Comment: Subsequent in the happens-before order; not in the real-time order. A read will see the most recent write before it in the happens-before order, or a write it is in data race with. That defines happens-before consistent.

Comment: @matt a good example that violates the real-time order is the use of store buffers in CPUs. Stores are placed in the store buffer, to prevent stalling the CPU, and the store will not be immediately visible. First, the store needs to retire (so isn't speculative anymore) and then it can take some time for the store to leave the store buffer and to be committed to the coherent cache (e.g the store needs to do an RFO and wait for the acknowledgment of invalidation of the corresponding cache line from all other CPUs). Only when it is committed, it is visible to other CPUs.

Comment: @matt so imagine that a thread would only execute a volatile store and do nothing else, then it is obvious that this store isn't visible when it is executed, not visible when it retires, not visible when it enters the linefillbuffer and the request for ownership (RFO) is send, but only visible at the moment it is committed to the cache. So if there would be another thread (different CPU) that executes only a volatile read and this volatile read is performed before the RFO is processed, it is allowed to return the value before the store has executed even though the store has executed/retired.

Comment: @matt But unless you have the ability to actually measure the timing of every state of an instruction on every CPU, you will not be able to prove the realtime order was violated. If the real-time order needs to be preserved, you need linearizability. Linearizability = sequential consistency + (pretending) to respect the real time order. With linearizability you get the guarantee that the operation will take effect between invocation start and completion (its linearization point); which clearly isn't the case with a store buffer.

https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/linearizable

Comment: @matt Another cause of loads/stores being skewed is the out-of-order processing abilities of a modern processor with can lead to loads and stores to move around with respect to the 'program order'. E.g. a load could be moved forward (executed earlier) and therefore see an old value instead of a newer value compared to if it would have been executed in order.

Comment: @matt this is a very good read: happening-before != happens-before.

https://preshing.com/20130702/the-happens-before-relation/

Comment: @pveentjer I am asking about the claim, "`running2=false`takes a very long time to propagate to another thread." Which is a bit ambiguous, but it is describing the application not ending within seconds after running2 is set to false. The effects you a writing about are going to be on the order of clock cycles not seconds? Maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: According to the specification it is allowed to skew for a very long period since there are no real time guarantees given. But from an implementation point of view I would already would be surprised if it takes more than a few hundred nanoseconds. The store buffer has a limited capacity and the CPU  tries to drain the store buffer as fast as possible because otherwise, the CPU would need to stall (store buffer will fill up and no store instructions can be scheduled).

Comment: @matt keep in mind that the compiler can change the code so that a load or store never becomes visible. So the skew would be indefinite.

Comment: @pveentje I think that is explicitly what volatile is to protect against. The next read needs to be needs to be there changed version. There are some practical concerns, but reading/writing a volatile field is synchronized.

Comment: @matt if nothing is done with the value, then there are no recency guarantees. That is the reason why using volatiles to simulate fences doesn't work. https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_15_VolatilesAreNotFences.java

Comment: I agree with that completely, I take that to mean `running2` will be updated, but `running` might not be updated.

Comment: @matt My understanding is that also running2 doesn't need to be updated since nobody is there to observe the read value. So since the value isn't used, nobody is there to proof that the value wasn't read.

Answer (score 1):

Both other answers say the main reason for the behavior in the question is the fact that the JMM doesn't guarantee a volatile write to become visible to other thread in some finite time.

Recently I've stumbled upon some additional information related to this topic and I would like to share it here because it might be useful to people interested in this topic.
The information is from ["The Java Memory Model"](https://rsim.cs.uiuc.edu/Pubs/popl05.pdf) article written by the authors of the JMM:

> ```java
>                     Initially, v is volatile and v = false                 
> Thread 1                             | Thread 2                            
> -------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
> while (!v);                          | v = true;                           
> System.out.println("Thread 1 done"); | System.out.println("Thread 2 done");
> ```
>
> If we observe print message by thread 2, Thread 1 must see write to v, print its message and terminate. But program can also be observed to hang and not print any messages.
>
> **Figure 9: Fairness Example**
>
> ...
>
> ... in Figure 9, if we observe the print message from Thread 2, and no threads other than Threads 1 and 2 are running, then Thread 1 must see the write to v, print its message and terminate. This prevents the compiler from hoisting the volatile read of v out of the loop in Thread 1.
> The fact that Thread 1 must terminate if the print by Thread 2 is observed follows from the rules on observable actions. If the print by Thread 2 is in a set of observable actions *O*, then the write to v and all reads of v that see the value 0 must also be in *O*. Additionally, the program cannot perform an unbounded amount of additional actions that are not in *O*. Therefore, the only observable behavior of this program in which the program *hangs* (runs forever without performing additional external actions) is one in which it performs no observable external actions other than hanging. This includes the print action.

As you can see in some cases (such as the example in Figure 9) volatile writes must become visible to other threads because of the rules in [17.4.9. Observable Behavior and Nonterminating Executions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.9).