# Are object parameters of synchronized block guranteed visibilty Synchronized Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, memory-barriers

I cannot find an answer for the following case:

```
  public class Example {
    int a=0;

    public  synchronized void method(Object x){
        a++;
        x.value=x.value+1;
    }
}
```

I know that happens-before relation is established for the same object lock , so everything should be written to the memory (but not sure if everything here include changes to x ) ,

my question : are the changes to the object x guranteed to be visible for other thread if they are using the same lock ? ( lock is on example object , but not on x itself)

Comment: "Everything" includes everything—even `x`. The lock is not _on_ anything except itself. Locking in synchronized blocks is purely [advisory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)#Types).

Answer (score 0):

> Are the changes to the object `x` guaranteed to be visible for other thread if they are using the same lock?

Yes, but this may not be useful.

First I need to turn your example code into something that compiles, and can be used to illustrate your question.

```
public class Example {
    int a = 0;

    public  synchronized void method(X x){
        a++;
        x.value = x.value+1;
    }
}

public class X {
    int value;
}
```

The scenario is then as follows:

0. An instance of `Example` and `Shared` are created and passed to two threads A and B.
1. Thread A calls `example.method(x)` with the common instances.
2. Some time later Thread B calls `example.method(x)` with the common instances.

There will be a *happens before* relation between thread A releasing the mutex on the `Example` instance and thread B acquiring this.  When we combine this with *happens before* relations for the sequential execution of the body of `method`, we will get a guarantee that

- EITHER Thread B will see the updated value of the `value` variable written by A
- OR it will see another value written after that.

Furthermore, if *any* code writes to `x.value` outside of a `method` call, or using a different `Example` instance as a lock, then all bets are off.  And there are no guarantees about what another thread would see if it read `x.value` directly.

---

In summary, there is some guaranteed behavior, but because of the caveats surrounding the guarantee, it is difficult to exploit them safely.  It would be better to do one of the following:

- lock directly on the `X` instances; e.g. via a synchronized `increment` method on `X`), or
- hide the `X` instances so that they are only operated on by (for example) `synchronized` methods of `Example`.

Comment: just to stay in the context of the question , happens before relations  gurantee visibility for all objects modified by thread regardless it's a lock or any other object , can you please confirm that ?

Comment: It guarantees visibility of memory writes to shared variables, not objects.   And the guarantees are as I described them complete with the caveats.  I'm not going to restate them in the looser terminology that you are using because it is ambiguous.   Particularly in the context of your example ... which is also an example of how NOT to write multi-threaded code!

Comment: I think that the answer is "yes" ... but it might be "no" ... depending on what you *understand* visibility to mean.

Comment: Visibility means : A , B are threads using the same lock object. if thread A modifies any object inside the synchrnise block , then block B should have visiblity to all objects modified by A ( including the lock object )

Comment: That is too vague / high level.  The actual guarantees are at the level of reads and writes to variables that are accessible to multiple threads.  If you are going to try to do hairy things that involve access to shared variables outside of synchronized blocks (or equivalent), you HAVE TO do the *happens before* analysis, at the level of the variable reads and writes.  (IMO) You can't take the mental short-cuts that you are attempting.  But ... frankly ... you should not write code like that.  It is too fragile / too difficult to understand.

Comment: I didn't say outside synchronized blocks, the access is inside synchronized blocks but not on the lock object. thats it

Comment: So how is the value of `x.value` observed by other code?  I assume that it must be observed ... otherwise this example is pointless.  (What is the point of incrementing a field that nothing else looks at?)  I am aware that this example is artificial, but surely it is motivated by a real scenario.

Comment: The example to undestand the basics , let X be an object passed to a method  , for both threads they have the same X and they have synchrnoised on the same object ( Example ). which means both threads cannot work in parallel as they have the same lock. They should see the latest update on X from each other ofcourse , because happens before established here

Comment: And if you are going to argue about what your (incomplete, non-compiling) example means, perhaps you should **take the time** to replace the code with something that 1) is complete and compilable, and 2) does something remotely practical.  (Right now we just have code that ... well ... a sensible programmer wouldn't do it that way.  A moot example.)

Comment: Actually I found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108541/happens-before-relationships-with-volatile-fields-and-synchronized-blocks-in-jav
Same thing in volatile , which proves my point

"When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile variable."