# Can we use volatile writes exclusively to enforce cache coherence?

Tags: java, memory, concurrency, keyword, volatile

I have encountered the following claim: "Reading or writing to a volatile variable imposes a memory barrier in which the entire cache is flushed/invalidated."

Now consider the following execution scenario:

*initial* `volatile boolean barrier;`
*initial* `int b = 0;`

*thread 1* `b = 1; // write1`
*thread 1* `barrier = true; // write2`
*thread 2* `barrier = true; // write3`
*thread 2* `print(b); // r1`

Question: is thread 2 guaranteed to print 1?

Based on the claim, I would answer yes: thread 1 flushes its cache on write2 (so that `b = 1` ends up in main memory), and thread 2 invalidates its cache on write3 (so that it will read `b` from main memory).

However, in the relevant [JLS sections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4-320) I am unable to find a guarantee for this behaviour, since write3 is a write, and not a read. Thus the following seemingly crucial clause does not apply:

> A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent **reads** of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

Is there some other information I am missing, or am I perhaps misunderstanding something?

(Relevant questions:

- [Volatile variables and other variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438464/volatile-variables-and-other-variables)
- [Is a write to a volatile a memory-barrier in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688697/is-a-write-to-a-volatile-a-memory-barrier-in-java))

Comment: How would you ensure that the `write3` in thread 2 happens after `write1` in thread1? If you can ensure that the writes happen in that order then I guess `b == 1` would be seen in thread 2.

Comment: @jepio: I did not mean to ensure anything - merely describe a possible execution scenario. In that case, then, would it not be possible for thread 2 to read a cached/stale value for b?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you highlighted a wrong word in the phrase you quoted (I mean, the fact that it synchronizes with reads is by far not the main issue here): "A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads **of v** by any thread". 
Note that it does not say anything at all about reads of other variables. Thread-1's version of `b` might still be sitting in the register for all you know.

Comment: "Thread-1's version of b might still be sitting in the register for all you know." Would this contradict the claim I opened my question with, given the execution?

Answer (score 0):

Reasoning of volatile in terms of cache flushing/invalidation will lead to more confusion and it doesn't present the full picture.

***A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).***

volatile write of variable followed by a read of that variable in other thread establishes a weaker consistency in terms of happens before gaurantee.

***i.e changing a little in op code***

```
thread 1 b = 1; // write1
thread 1 barrier = true; // write2
thread 2 while(!barrier) // read barrier
thread 2 print(b); // r1
```

now it is guaranteed to print b as 1.

Now if you see when thread 2 reads barrier as true and then thread 2 is guaranteed to see everything which happened before writing to barrier in program order.

If you need to see volatile in terms of barrier then please refer 
http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html.

In brief volatile implementation invoke two kinds of things
first compiler is restricted in what can be optimize w.r.t to volatile read and write. Secondly and more importantly it is implemented

```
    as volatile read -> loadload 
       volatile wtire - > storeStore|loadStore  
before write and StoreLoad after write.
```

here loadload means process the [invalidate queue](http://www.puppetmastertrading.com/images/hwViewForSwHackers.pdf)
before reading the next value ensures reading lates values.
StoreStore means flush store buffer before writing the next value.

http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html.
http://www.puppetmastertrading.com/images/hwViewForSwHackers.pdf