# Mixing volatile and non-volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

My question applies to a field which is initially `null`, then is initialised to a non-`null` value, and then doesn’t change anymore.

As this field needs to be available as soon as possible to all threads, I need to use `volatile`.

But if I want to avoid the overhead of `volatile` access whenever possible (i.e. when a non-`volatile` field is enough), would the following code make any sense?

```
public class User {
  private String nonVolatileName;
  private volatile String volatileName;

  public String getName() {
    final String name = nonVolatileName;
    return name != null ? name : volatileName;
  }

  private void initName() {
    volatileName = nonVolatileName = expensiveComputation();
  }

  …
}
```

Comment: Your getName() method must be synchronized, and this is an overhead too

Comment: @LeoLeontev I don’t see why `getName` must be synchronized.

Comment: "name != null ?" is an overhead as well. Are you sure the overhead of volatile is bigger? (I think some clever benchmark should be able to prove this).

Comment: @Suma I agree, I need to run a benchmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the code will work because *"A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field."*  [1]

```
return name != null ? name : volatileName;
```

so as long as `name == null` you will be forcing a read from a volatile variable until it is not null (i.e. `expensiveComputation` has completed) which given the happen before semantics ensures that you see the non null value in `nonVolatileName` from then onward. See also here [2]

Have fun explaining this to your colleagues though

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-320

[2] [Volatile variables and other variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438464/volatile-variables-and-other-variables)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! is there a simpler way of doing that in Java?

Comment: It is rather ugly isn't it? Do you really have a use case where using/not using  `volatile` this way makes a tangible difference?

Comment: Well, intellectually it seems that it can make a difference because this field is accessed very frequently; but as suggested by Suma I need to run a benchmark in order to prove it (or not).

Comment: I you have time, please, post the benchmark result here as a comment, I am curious to learn what will you see.

Comment: @Suma the benchmark is here: https://github.com/julienroyer/mixing-volatile-and-non-volatile - it might be wrong as I am an absolute beginner with benchmark tools. The result I got (see the results directory) suggests that the difference is not noticeable.